# d3 nested selection : how to access array data

Tags: tree, d3.js

I have had a look at many similar posts here about nested selections, but I wasn't successful transferring the problem to my case.
I hope it's ok to ask this as a separate question.

I have:
nested json structure that represents a phylogenetic tree (with species)

```
    {
   "name" : "Sauria",
   "children" : [
      {
         "domains" : [
            {
               "name" : "BRCA2",
               "domain_start" : 100,
               "domain_stop" : 240
            }
         ],
         "common_name" : "NaN",
         "seq_length" : 200,
         "duplication" : "N",
         "name" : "ENSMGAP00000010132",
         "class" : "leaf",
         "bootstrap" : "NaN",
         "taxon" : "Meleagris_gallopavo"
      },
      {
         "domains" : [
            {
               "name" : "BRCA2",
               "domain_start" : 100,
               "domain_stop" : 240
            }
         ],
         "common_name" : "NaN",
         "seq_length" : 200,
         "duplication" : "N",
         "name" : "ENSACAP00000006049",
         "class" : "leaf",
         "bootstrap" : "NaN",
         "taxon" : "Anolis_carolinensis"
      }
    ],
   "bootstrap" : "15",
   "taxon" : null,
   "common_name" : "NaN"
```

To get all nodes and bind my data I do

```
 var node = d3.select("#tree svg").selectAll("g.node").data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
```

Then I add groups to each node using

```
 var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; });
```

I draw a rectangle for each leaf like this

```
 var div3 = nodeEnter.append("rect")
            .attr("x", 192)
            .attr("y", 160)
             .attr("width", function(d){return d.children ? "":"10";})
             .attr("height", function(d){
                   return d.children ? "": domainOnlyScale(d.seq_length);
            })
           .attr("transform", function(d){return d.children ? "":"rotate(-90 100 100)";})
           .attr("fill", function(d){return d.children ? "":"grey";});
```

Now the tricky thing. I would like to draw something onto the rectangle using the data in "domains" that each leaf has, so this part

```
   "domains" : [
        {
           "name" : "BRCA2",
           "domain_start" : 100,
           "domain_stop" : 240
        }
     ],
```

I simply don't know how to iterate over all leaves and over each element of the domains array (note that this array can have several entries). So when I try to use "each"

```
 div3.each(function(d) {    
        [d.domains].each(function(dom){
                    d3.select(this)
                   .append("rect")
                   .attr("x", 230)
                   .attr("y", 175)
                   .attr("rx", 5)
                   .attr("ry", 5)
                   .attr("width", function(d){return "12";})
                   .attr("height", function(d){
                        console.log("here we go again: "+d.name+" has length: "+(d.domains.seq_stop - d.domains.seq_start));
                           //var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
                           return dom.domain_start;
                    })
                    .attr("fill", function(d){return d.children ? "":"red";})
       })
       });
```

d3 tells me that "Object [object Object] has no method 'each' ", but I though d.domains was an array.

Can you help me to access this nested "domain" information?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

In a nested selection, you should pass the nested data as an argument to the `data()` function of a selection. So instead of doing `div3.each`, it would look something like this.

```
div3.selectAll("rect").data(function(d) { return d.domains; }).enter()
    .append("rect")
    ...
```

You should be able to use the rest of the code unchanged.

Comment: nice, that works. Thanks!  But currently, I add a rect as a child to a rect and the added rects seems to be hidden behind the firstly created ones.   How can I avoid that? The html looks like this: <rect x="192" y="160" width="10" height="100" transform="rotate(-90 100 100)" fill="grey"><rect x="230" y="175" rx="5" ry="5" width="12" height="140" fill="red"></rect></rect>

Comment: You could add the rectangles you want to be at the front first. Save the selection in a variable and append in the order you want.

Comment: exactly, but isn't that what I do? I save the selection in the variable "div3" and append further rectangles with div3.selectAll("rect").data(...)  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yes, but you do that after appending the other stuff. All you should need to do is change the order of the statements that append things :)

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. Unfortunately, it is still not working. I have managed to put all my code in a jsfiddle. Maybe you could have a quick look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fabsta/HRHZz/1/)?  The important part starts at line 193. Thanks so much!

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to do there. The second insertion of rectangles after line 193 does nothing however because you're binding it to already existing data and using the `.enter()` selection. I've updated it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fabsta/HRHZz/1/) removing the data binding and fixing the way the length is calculated. Is that closer to what you want?

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fabsta/F9Ygs/) of what I would the rectangles to look like. So, 1. create a long rectangle of length "seq_length",and 2. attach a rectangle for each domain. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/HRHZz/3/ ? You should really replace all those hard coded position values though.

Comment: very cool! Thanks a lot, Lars. That is exactly what I wanted. I will avoid hard coded position values as much as possible