# D3 nested selection with json: how to apply .force() to nested elements?

Tags: json, graph, d3.js, force-layout

(This is a follow-up question to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481570/how-to-link-extra-attributes-from-json-data-in-a-d3-js-force-layout). The issue has not been resolved completely in that question, and this is kind of a continuation, so I post a new question)

I have a nested json structure representing a tree, which looks something like this:

```
 [{
   "name": "flare",
   "root": "true",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "analytics",
     "nestedproperties": [
         { "attribute": "attribute1", 
           "type": "type1" },
         { "attribute": "attribute2", 
           "type": "type2" },
         { "attribute": "attribute3", 
           "type": "type3" }
     ],
     "children": [
      {
         "name": "cluster",
         "nestedproperties": [
             { "attribute": "attribute4", 
               "type": "type4"},
             ....
         ]
      },
  ...
```

Besides displaying the normal tree structure with nodes and their children, I want to represent each element under  `nestedproperties` with circles that link to their parent node.

By following the answers to some other questions and other examples I managed to display each of the elements of `nestedproperties` by passing the nested data as argument to `.data()`,  as advised in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580604/d3-nested-selection-how-to-access-array-data). The  core part of the code looks like this:

```
  var pii = nodeEnter.selectAll("circle.pii")
       .data(function(d) {return d.nestedproperties; })


  var piiEnter = pii.enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "piinode")
      .attr("transform", "translate(50,50)") 
      //.attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })    // <<--- I cannot call this function because d.x and d.y does not exist
      .call(forcepii.drag);

  // Append the circle for the node 
  piiEnter.append("svg:circle")
      .attr("class", "pii")
      .attr("r", 25)
      .style("fill", "blue")
      .style("stroke", "#999999")
```

The full code is in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djjupa/n93Xw/2/).

The problem is that the circles representing the elements inside nestedproperties appear all on top of each other and cannot be dragged.  I don't understand how to apply `force.nodes()` to the nested elements or how to use the `transform` property on them to do the ticking.

Trying the following tells me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'index' of undefined "

```
   forcepii.nodes(function(d) { return d.nestedproperties; })
    //.links(links)
    .gravity(0.05)
    .charge(-1500)
    .linkDistance(100)
    .friction(0.5)
    .linkStrength(function(l, i) {return 1; })
    .size([w, h])
    //.on("tick", tick)
    .start();
```

Here is the resulting picture. As you can see the circles are drawn on top of each other and force is not being applied:

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

At the end I found out how this is done. Here is a gist showing a live example: http://bl.ocks.org/djjupa/5655723

Since my data was "flexible" I recoded it to have "children" elements as the nested selections, so it looks like this:

```
[{
   "name": "flare",
   "root": "true",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "analytics",
     "nestedproperties": {
         "children": [
              { "attribute": "attribute1", 
                "type": "type1" },
              { "attribute": "attribute2", 
                "type": "type2" },
              { "attribute": "attribute3", 
                "type": "type3" }
          ]
     },
     "children": [
      {
         "name": "cluster",
         "nestedproperties": {
               "children": [
                   { "attribute": "attribute4", 
                     "type": "type4"
                   },
                      ....
               ]
         }
      },
  ...
```